# Overleaf: PDF does not show up (Using Multiple PDFs in one)

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, multiple-files

I am usually not using Overleaf, but for one collaborative project I have to ... A functionality I am very frequently using is to create figures using TIKZ, and then transform them to PDF as a standalone figure. Then, I can directly include them in the main paper (and since I only specify the path, I do not have to update the reference, or re-upload the PDF).

I tried to do something similar in Overleaf, created a folder "Figures" which contains the .tex files (and should also contain the .pdf files). However, since the PDF is never saved, I cannot reference the PDF from my main document.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Your description does not make much sense. What exactly did you place in that figures folder? Did you upload the pdfs or not? They aren't magically created from the tex files. Since it is very common to have figures in a separate folder that normally also work on overleaf. Thus we need to know **exactly** what you did. If you cannot explain it, it might be an idea to contact overleaf support